# How do I smooth out spray paint drips on a metal monitor stand?

Tags: painting, spraying

I purchased [this monitor stand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FNPNO0). However, I did not like the color. So I sprayed painted it semi-gloss black with [this spray paint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BWORSG). Suffice to say, I'm not very handy. It ended up un-smooth on the curved edges because of paint drips.

How should I go about smoothing it out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is only one way to fix your boo-boo.  Sand it back down to metal or enough to remove the drips.  Next time, when using spray paint, remember several very thin coats are much better than one heavy coat.  Always start the spray away from the object you want to paint. Move smoothly and fairly quickly across the area, then go past the end of the work before stopping the spray. Let the paint dry a bit before the next coat. Be patient, smooth and quick. Trying to put on too much at one time caused your drips.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you sir. Any specific product you recommend for sanding? Paint thinner won't work? I'm clueless about this---if you couldn't tell by the "boo-boo".

Comment: Seeing the piece you painted, it doesn't look like a big job to sand it. Use 150 to get the most off, then some 220 or some 0000 steel wool to smooth it good before repainting it. Just be sure it is very smooth to the touch, clean it good with a little mineral spirits and start again as I instructed. I appreciate kkeilman's remarks, but way too much work for the piece you have to deal with. Get the messed up paint off and do it right this time. You can do it!!!

Comment: Thanks for the sharing of your wisdom! Very much appreciated. Heading to home depot this week and giving it a whirl sometime this coming weekend.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have heniously large runs/sags and drips you can wet sand that stuff out.

Get some 400, 1000, and 2000 grit "wet" sandpaper (the kind used by auto body guys).

using 00 to 0000 grade steel wool works about the same...

Small container of water and a work area you don't mind getting a little messy.

Wet sand the runs w/ 400 to remove as much of the runs and drip accumulation you can.  **Make sure to keep the area you're sanding wet and rinse the paper in the water constantly**.  Once you're relatively satisfied with your first pass, move to the higher grit paper and repeat.

Once it's smooth enough for you, you can polish with rubbing compound, et al to get the gloss back up.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

One other option would be to take to to a professional, have it sandblasted and power-coated.  Probably way more expensive than doing it yourself, but you'll end up with an attractive, durable finish.

Comment: The stand cost $23, power coating would cost at least $100. Sound like a good investment?

Comment: No, but some people value aesthetics more than a bit of money.  And $100 sounds a bit expensive.